# AWS Neptune Jupyter Notebook's Property Parameter Does Not Work

Tags: jupyter-notebook, amazon-neptune, graph-notebook

When displaying my vertices with specific properties,

```
my_node_labels = '{"User":"email","Group": "tag"}'
my_edge_labels = '{"Group":"relatedAs"}'
```

It shows the `email` property inn my graph display but it does not show the `tag` property.

Answer (score 0):

The parameter does not take any blank space. Eliminate all blank spaces in your parameter specifications.

```
 my_node_labels = '{"User":"email","Group":"tag"}'
 my_edge_labels = '{"Group":"relatedAs"}'
```